# What's this shower screen seal part called?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, bathroom-fixtures

Looking online to get new shower seals. The straight parts are fine and readily available, but it's an L-Shaped shower screen (has a square shower part at one end of the bath tub) and I can't seem to find this 'corner part' anywhere!

Anyone know what to search for for this part?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE. It's not clear what part of the shower that came from. Please edit your post to clarify.

Comment: It's the L part.

Comment: *Please edit your post to clarify,* and use more words than that. I still have no idea what that is. A photo of the primary component would help.

Comment: I can't post any more pictures. This is the bath https://www.bathroomsupastore.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/420x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/l/e/leda_l_shape_shower_bath_1500_x_850_left_hand.jpg. This part is on the corner of the screen where the bath goes narrow.

Comment: Is this from the corner of the metal frame extrusion?  pushes up in the metal?

Comment: Yes it inserts in to the metal,